# Using quotations and commas in a list format

Tags: quotes

Is this correct ...

... accustomed to phrases such as: “War”, “Random Searches”, “Security Checkpoints”, “Weapons of Mass Destruction”, and “Acceptable Losses”.

or should it be ...

... accustomed to phrases such as: "War," "Random Searches," Security Checkpoints," "Weapons of Mass Destruction," and "Acceptable Losses."

Comment: The answer probably varies between British English and American English, so both may be correct. But I would suggest italicizing these phrases, rather than using quotation marks, both for visual appeal/simplicity and since you seem to not be quoting a specific individual/source.

Comment: Either way, the comma after the penultimate item (before the _and_) should be omitted.

Comment: Unless you accept that the OUP knows better than you.

Comment: @DavidR Are you kidding? That's an Oxford comma. I was raised on those things.

Answer (score 1):

Americans always include punctuation *within* quote marks, but Brits normally don't (not in OP's construction, anyway).

The comma after the penultimate item (before the and) is an [Oxford/serial/Harvard comma](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/QAoxfordcomma.htm), which so far as I know isn't really a UK/US split - it's just a matter of personal/house style.

I don't think it's meaningful to discuss whether “War” or "War" is correct. Typesetters obviously use the "matched pair", but not everyone has easy access to the appropriate symbol set. I know I could have "cut & pasted" them into that last sentence - I just didn't think it was worth the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Use semi-colons to separate the complex list:
War; Random Searches; Security Checkpoints; Weapons of Mass Destruction; and Acceptable Losses.